# Why won't this SQL string work?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join

I have to get a list of all the job_titles and the sum of the salaries of the people working there...

I got that using this:

```
SELECT j.job_title, SUM(e.salary)
FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.job_id = j.job_id
GROUP BY j.job_title;
```

OK, but now I gotta get the same list but also considering the city...

It doens't work... :/

```
SELECT j.job_title, SUM(e.salary), d.department_id, l.city
FROM departments d LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id LEFT JOIN locations l 
ON l.location_id = d.location_id LEFT JOIN jobs j ON e.job_id = j.job_id 
GROUP BY l.city;
```

Why could that be?

Comment: maybe you can try `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 5):

you also need to add these columns on the group by clause: `j.job_title`, `d.department_id`, `l.city`

```
SELECT..
FROM...
GROUP BY j.job_title, d.department_id, l.city
```

*NON-aggregated columns* must be included on the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Your last sentence isn't true for mysql generally, but true for this case

Comment: @Bohemian it will be true if you prevent the default behavior for the GROUP BY clause by adding the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode variable to your `SQL_MODE` system variable.

Comment: It now shows nonsense stuff :S but thanks, now the problem is about the sql itself and not the grouping.

Comment: @user1880778 the best way you will to do help us solve your problemis to add sample records, and desire result in your question. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to group by department_id and job_title also:

```
GROUP BY j.job_title, d.department_id, l.city;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the non-aggregated columns;

```
...
group by job_title, department_id, city
```

You may also use column positions in a group by:

```
group by 1, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only group by l.city but in the select statement you are using  j.job_title, d.department_id  so in order to fetch these values you have to use

```
group by job_title, department_id, city
```